# Downcasting from shared pointer of base class to reference of derived class

Tags: c++, c++11, shared-ptr

I'm learning to use shared pointers.

Lets say we have two classes, `Base` and `Derived` (inheriting from `Base`), *without* polymorphism (no virtual method, except destructor), and a loop :

```cpp
for (std::shared_ptr<Base>& pB : collection)
{
  <downcast>
  ...
}
```

Which of the following would be the best `<downcast>` in terms of code quality, good practices, performances, or any other reason?

```cpp
(1) Derived& d = static_cast<Derived&>(*pB);
```

```cpp
(2) Derived& d = *(std::static_pointer_cast<Derived>(pB).get());
```

Comment: Number one. static_pointer_cast is only needed for making a copy of that shared pointer, which you don't need in this case.

Comment: If you do this within CRTP, the both are ok. Otherwise, the both are equally bad.

Comment: `Base` and `Derived` do a 'traditional' inheritance : `class Derived : public Base {...}`

Answer (score 0):

Since your classes are not polymorphic, you are on a thin ice, since you cannot check whether the downcasting is valid at runtime. If not, you likely end up with *undefined behavior*. Static casting if fine, but only if you are (more than) 100% sure that `pB` in all the iterations points to an object of type `Derived`.

Likely the best practice / safest solution would be to add a virtual destructor to `Base` and use dynamic casting:

```
Derived& d = dynamic_cast<Derived&>(*pB);
```

Which will throw an exception if the casting is invalid. Of course, this solution would be less efficient due to a runtime check for downcasting validity.

Comment: I strongly disagree with your comment on Arne J's answer.  His answer absolutely *was* an answer, and your answer (while it is good extra commentary) neither explicitly says "don't do that", nor answers the question.  I have voted to undelete it, and if it is undeleted, I will upvote it.

Comment: @MartinBonnersupportsMonica I revisited the deleted answer and you're right, my bad (I kind of expected more reasoning about performance, good practice, ...). Unfortunately, I cannot vote to undelete it, but will upvote if it happens. Thanks for pointing this out.

Comment: I forgot to mention that `Base` already have a virtual destructor. I didn't know it was a sufficient condition to concider a class relationship as polymorphic

Comment: @MartinBonnersupportsMonica Can someone re-post a summary of Arne J's answer? The credit will go for him indeed ;)

Comment: @Gupta: The entire text of the answer was: "Number one. static_pointer_cast is only needed for making a copy of that shared pointer, which you don't need in this case"

Comment: @A.Gille Ah!  That completely changes the answer.  Yes, a virtual destructor is a virtual method, and gives a class a vtable.  In that case, dynamic_cast to a reference is *definitely* the right answer.